# VerificationController uses uniqueIdentifier

Tags: iphone, ios, security, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to patch [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html) security breach that Apple has identified. Only, the sample code (VerificationController) they provide uses this line:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier
```

Which has been deprecated and has had apps rejected from the app store. Any idea if this is OK again? or what is happening here?

Comment: I guess it's an obsolete doc, that they did not update yet, because of this or that. "uniqueIdentifier" is still a matter of rejection.

Comment: Is there a reason you could not use UUID (as opposed to UDID) for your app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has updated the sample code deleting lines where UDID had been used.

[In-App Purchase Receipt Validation on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

## UDID vs UUID

From what I understand, Apple does not want developers to have access to a UDID (unique device identifier) anymore as it is not within an app's [sandbox](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html).

Think of a situation where a user gets a new iOS device (with a different UDID). Just because there is a new device does not necessarily mean there is a new user. Also, if someone gets a device previously used by someone else, we do not want to assume that because we have the same device, the same user must be using it.

Apple recommends using a UUID (universally unique identifier) for your apps instead. The only reason Apple allowed you to use UDID before was because they had not implemented UUID yet or had not considered the situations above (to my understanding). UUID's are generated for the object you want to keep track of (e.g. a user).

Basically, **Apple's mentality is that you should keep track of users** (or other instances)**, not devices.**

---

### Generating a UUID

To generate a UUID, try the including the following as a class method:

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{
  CFUUIDRef uuidReference = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
  NSString *theUUID = [(NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidReference) autorelease];
  CFRelease(uuidReference);
  return theUUID;
}
```

For my experience, I've called this method in the `init` method and stored the resulting `NSString` as a property of the instance that was just created.

Comment: This won't work in the VerificationController code. They use the uniqueIdentifier to validate the device from the transaction receipt.

Comment: oh i see, the VerificationController is provided by Apple... I would assume that if Apple gave you that code, you should be able to use it without altering it.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Where did you hear that apps were rejected because of using it?  Maybe they were using it maliciously but it is a public API.</del>  Also, look at the note on the page you linked to.

> Note: This listing uses the symbols kSecTrustInfoExtendedValidationKey and SecTrustCopyInfo, which are not public API. Your app is allowed to use them for this specific purpose.

If they are even willing to let you use private APIs for this purpose, I doubt they would care about a public one.

Comment: I have had an app rejected because of this. Search the net

Comment: @PauldeLange I did find some articles like that (seems a bit like bad play to me...), but I stand by the last portion of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's problem with the UDID was always that they consider it private information, and so they were rejecting apps that sent it to, say, a server, without asking permission first. If you're just using it locally, I don't think you'll have trouble.